# Visualization of (Gaussian, Laplacian, etc.) filters in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, matlab-figure

How is it possible to visualize filters the way it is presented in the following website:

http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/texclass/filters.html

For example, in Fig.1 the last four square subimages visualize four different Gaussian filters.

Answer (score 3):

They're just images after all, the only trick is to use the right scale. Fortunately this is pretty easy in MATLAB.

So if your filter is G, then to visualize it you can just do

```
imshow(G,[])
```

The [ ] will set the right scale for you (min_value, max_value).

So for example, for a Gaussian of sigma 30 (that high for visualization purposes here) these lines:

```
G1=fspecial('gauss',[round(6*sigma), round(6*sigma)], sigma);
imshow(G1,[]);
```

Lead to this image:

[image]

Same principle for any image you want to display that has an unusual range (i.e. different from [0 255]).

To visualize multiple images at once you have to use [subplot](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a little bonus, but because the filter is a 2D function, we can also map the amplitude of the function in the `Z` direction as well.  You would basically take the intensity that is shown in `imshow` and just map it to the third dimension.  In other words, replicating what @cifz has done, we can also define a 2D grid, then use `mesh` or `surf` to visualize it in 3D.

As such:

```
sigma = 30;
G1=fspecial('gauss',[round(6*sigma), round(6*sigma)], sigma);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:size(G1,2), 1:size(G1,1));
mesh(X, Y, G1);
xlabel('X'); ylabel('Y'); zlabel('Amplitude');
title('3D visualization of the Gaussian filter');
colorbar;
```

You'd get:

[image]

This is obviously not what the OP wanted, but I figured I'd add this bonus in case anyone was curious.